# How and where can i find the correct data of meshes in pyassimp?

Tags: python, struct, 3d, blender, assimp

Im writing a game in python and Im working on a scalable solution for 3D data files like .blend, .dae, .3ds, .obj and so on

I have installed assimp via pyassimp and its library.
It works nice for litte meshes/scenes but if i want to make it "scalable" the problems begin.

First of all I know, that a full scene can be created seperatly with multiple parts and in combination of its vertices, normals, and indices it can be rendered good.
But where do I find the corresponding texture files (materials) to each "texturecoords" each mesh of the scene? Or is it stored in one big picture?
Either, how is the color of vertices be set, which have not "texturecoords"?
Is it right, that the calculation of light has its correct effect of the color, when the vertex start at white?

It is really difficult to get more information about the data-structure from pyassimp.
I looked at assimp doc for c++ but the most information, especially textures, do not have the corresponding function in python.
It would be awesome if someone could tell me how i find these things or where can i look up.

Greetings and wish you a healthy start into the new year. :)